# Rundeck failing execution of ansible commands/playbooks

Tags: ansible, rundeck

I have ansible playbook that restore aws MySQL RDS from snapshot. If run, manually from command-line, the playbook runs well and do the tasks. But when run through the web interface of `rundeck`, following error is encountered,

```
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the remote directory. Consider changing the remote temp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1491222004.1-29099027555878 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1491222004.1-29099027555878=\"` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1491222004.1-29099027555878 `\" ), exited with result 1", "unreachable": true}
```

My Rundeck server on the same Ansible server

I tried to add the line below in ansible.cfg

```
remote_tmp = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
local_tmp = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
```

I set privilege 1777 for $HOME/.ansible/tmp already but it didn't solve my problem.
Could you please help?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you running an inline script?

Comment: No, I'm using rundeck-anible plugin and "Runs an Ansible Playbook"

Comment: Anything in log file /var/log/rundeck/service.log? Looks like a file permission issue.

Comment: INFO  ScheduledExecutionService: scheduling immediate job run: TEMP:hung:2:79
WARN  ExecutionJob: ExecutionJob: Execution not found with ID [79], will retry for up to 60 seconds...
INFO  ExecutionJob: ExecutionJob: Execution found with ID [79] retried (1)
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
ERROR ExecutionUtilService: Execution failed: 79 in project Shop-Ansible: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=AnsibleNonZero: ERROR: Ansible execution returned with non zero code.}, status: failed]

Comment: Which version of ansible are you running on?

Comment: I'm using ansible 2.2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

set those in ansible.cfg:

```
remote_tmp = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
local_tmp = $HOME/.ansible/tmp
```

[Ansible issue #21339](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/21339)

Comment: I got this error:
==
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the remote directory. Consider changing the remote temp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1491187408.79-62648068739250 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1491187408.79-62648068739250=\"` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1491187408.79-62648068739250 `\" ), exited with result 1", "unreachable": true}

Comment: @CharlesPHAM Your ansible user doesn't have access to $HOME/.ansible/

Comment: I'm using rundeck user and $HOME/.ansible is /var/lib/rundeck/.ansible. I set 1777 perimission for $HOME/.ansible already.